# How to use Authentication.Negotiate on ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication

I'm running ASP.NET Core on .NET framework 4.8, I'm trying to use Windows auth, all references I found requires me to use

```
services.AddAuthentication(...).AddNegotiate()...
```

in `ConfigureServices` and

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

on the controller.

The problem is I can't find which packages provide those functionalities, afaik it's `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate` in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and newer versions.

I have tried installing all nuget packages related to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` available for ASP.NET Core 2.1

Comment: If you want configure windows authentication in asp.net core, you can refer to this link: [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).